# How to restore a locally deleted file in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

I deleted a file & package from my local source dir and I'm trying to replace it using RTC. When I view 'pending changes' the file is not appearing so as to add it again. Also when I right click on the project and select 'Compare' there is no option to compare to the latest in the repository. Right clicking and viewing 'Team' also does not seem to have an option to compare. How do I restore a locally deleted file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload your repo workspace, except you can select the part of the project you want to load.

From "[Loading Content from a Jazz Source Control Repository in Rational Team Concert 2.0, 3.0 and 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/192/)":

[image: LoadFolder]

That will restore the latest checked-in version of your file in your local workspace.

You will see more options (for other cases of deletion) in the article "[Finding Lost Content with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/191/)".

Answer (score 2):

If its just a few files you need to reload, you can right click on that component and then select Show->Repository File

In the Repository Files browser, you can look for the file to restore. Right click and select "Load" or "Load As" (if you need to specify where to load it.